# Need option to fill values in Jenkins parameterized pipeline script stored in Github whenever it run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parameter-passing

I have created a jenkins parameterized pipeline script as below. I have stored it on my Github repository.

```
properties([parameters([string(defaultValue: 'Devasish', description: 'Enter your name', name: 'Name'), 
                        choice(choices: ['QA', 'Dev', 'UAT', 'PROD'], description: 'Where you want to deploy?', name: 'Environnment')])])

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('one') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello ${Name} Your code is Building in ${Environnment} "
            }
        }
        stage('Two') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello ${Name} hard testing in  ${Environnment}"
            }
        }
        stage('Three') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello1 ${Name} deploying in  ${Environnment}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have created a jenkins job by choosing pipeline option. While creating jenkins pipeline Under **build triggers** section, I have checked **GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling** checkbox and Under **Pipeline** section, I have chosen **Pipeline script from SCM** followed by choosing **Git** in SCM, providing Repository URL where the above written JenkinsFile script is stored.

Then, Under Github repository settings, I have gone to **webhooks** and added one webhook where I specified my Payload URL as *myJenkinsServerURL*/github-webhook/. which will enable a functionality like whenever there will be any push event occurred within the repository, it will run the jenkins pipeline I created above.

Now, the situation is, when I am running this jenkins job from Classic UI by clicking **Build with parameters**, I am getting a **text box** to fill my name and a **dropdown** having list of 4 options ('QA', 'Dev', 'UAT', 'PROD') I gave above in script to choose, in which server I want to deploy my code, then it gets run.

But when I am committing in Github, it starts jenkins pipeline but not asking for parameters value instead just taking default value **Devasish** in name and **QA** in server.

What should I do to get an option of filling these details but not from Classic UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Geet: Good job asking your question here, hope someone answers soon

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, when you trigger your pipeline manually, it will ask for the Build Parameters and let you specify values before proceeding.
However, when triggering the pipeline thru automatic triggers (e.g. SCM triggers/webhooks), then it is assumed to be an unattended build and it will use the `defaultValue` settings from your Jenkinsfile build parameters" definition.

Comment: Then Is there any way to get the option of specifying parameter values, when triggering the pipeline thru SCM webhooks?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to specify parameter values directly via the webhook setup. However, depending on your situation, you could have a secondary simple job triggered by the webhook, and that could analyze the conditions before invoking the primary job (now without webhook trigger) and setting appropriate parameter values. I have also seen a setup where that secondary job is replaced by a custom Jenkins plugin that receive and manipulates the webhook processing to set specific build parameter values, but this is certainly more involved.